# XPath to select parent containing only specific type of children?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this simple DOM :

```
<r>
  <a1>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <foo>...</foo>
  </a1>
  <a2>
    <faa>...</faa>
    <faa>...</faa>
    <foo>...</foo>
  </a2>
  <a3>
    <fii>...</fii>
    <fii>...</fii>
    <fii>...</fii>
  </a3>
</r>
```

Is it possible with only XPath to select the element `aX` (here in the example, the element `a1`) containing only `foo` children elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[foo][not(*[not(self::foo)])]
```

selects all elements that have `foo` child elements ***and no other child elements***.

### Explanation

- `//*` selects all elements in the document
- `//*[foo]` ...that have at least one `foo` child element
- `//*[foo][not(*[not(self::foo)])]` ...and do *not* have any child elements that are *not* `foo`.  Since we've already predicated that there must exist a `foo` child element, by adding that there can be no others that are not a `foo` child element, we guarantee that there are `foo` ***and only*** `foo` child elements, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath to get all elements that have "foo" elements as children

```
//*[foo]
```

Comment: This misses the requirement where OP specifies *containing **only** foo childs* -- it would select `a2` too.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @kjhughes's answer, two working XPath :

```
//foo[count(preceding-sibling::*)=count(preceding-sibling::foo)]/..
//*[starts-with(name(),"a")][count(.//*)=count(.//foo)]
```

Output :

```
<a1>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <foo>...</foo>
</a1>
```